# Adding a <div> after x amount of <ul>s

Tags: php, chat

I'm working on an anonymous chatroom, and in the lounge area of the chat, I would like to add a  tag containing an ad after x (6) rooms are shown (rooms are shown as s.) Here is a sample of the code echoed for each time a room is made.

```
<ul class="rooms unselect">
<input style="display:none;"  type="submit" name="login" value="<?php e(t("LOGIN")) ?>" class="right enter input inline" />
<!--</span>-->
<form action="<?php e($room['url']) ?>" method="post" class="inline">
<li class="name inline left <?php e($room['name']) ?>" title="(ID#: <?php e($room['id']) ?>)" style="color:<?php e($room['name']) ?>">
<input style="color:<?php e($room['name']) ?>; border: none; background: none; font-size: 20px;cursor: pointer;" type="submit" name="login" value="<?php e($room['name']) ?>"></input>
<?php $res = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $room['name']); ?>
</li>

<li class="creater"><?php e('Host: '.'['.$room['creater'].']') ?></li>

<li class="member inline right">
<?php e($room['total']) ?> / <?php e($room['limit']) ?>
</li>
<div style="margin-right: 20px;"><progress value="<?php e($room['total']) ?>" max="<?php e($room['limit']) ?>">
</progress></div>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php e($room['id']) ?>" />
</form>
<ul class="member_hold" style="display: none;">
<?php foreach ($room['users'] as $user) : ?>
<li class="inline">
<img class="inline" src="<?php echo DURA_URL; ?>/css/<?php echo $user['icon'] ?>.png" style="height:20px;"/>
<span style="position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;"><?php echo $user['name'] ?></span>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Modulo http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 1):

just try like below in your loop as I used in `<li>` you also apply same for `<ul>`

```
<?php foreach ($room['users'] as $key=>$user) : ?>
<li class="inline">
<img class="inline" src="<?php echo DURA_URL; ?>/css/<?php echo $user['icon'] ?>.png" style="height:20px;"/>
<span style="position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;"><?php echo $user['name'] ?></span>
</li>
<?php if($key % 6 == 0){ ?>
<div>your code goes here</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Mahipal Patel  The code breaks the rooms. It just adds the div after every user in the room listings. https://i.imgur.com/L3NQb53.jpg

Comment: i just give u idea, as i not able to see your full code. you just apply my condition in your code for appropriate effect.